# Clickable on items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I can't click on items in RecyclerView. For example, as shown in the code, I gave Tittle a click feature, but I can't click right now. In the same way I gave deleteimage a click feature, but I can't click. What do I need to do to make the items clickable? Where is the problem? I can't click on the items in RecyclerView, that's the problem.

**XML Source Code:**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/productImage"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/roomlocation" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:text="productAdi"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="Cihaza ait eklenmiş odalar"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/deleteproduct"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_yellow" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="stechome.berkeylen.firebasedatabase.RoomsActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvRooms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**RecyclerView Class Source:**

```
    public class RoomsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child("0").child("Rooms");

          public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
             public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                productImage = (ImageView)          

                itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
                title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                deleteImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteproduct);

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            String data = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                            Rooms.add(data);

             title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                                    int position = 0;
                                    position = getAdapterPosition();
                                    if (getAdapterPosition() == position){
                                        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("0");
                                        rootRef.child("titles").child("0").child("places").setValue(Rooms.get(position));
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                        }

                        deleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {

                     if (v == deleteproduct) {
                                  deleteproduct(getLayoutPosition());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Comment: I can't click on the items in RecyclerView, that's the problem.

Comment: Yeah I know you're unable to click on Items in recyclerview, but everything that I see in your Adapter code seems wrong to me. 1. You fetch data inside the activity, and then pass it to adapter. 2. You write code for click listener inside the onBindViewHolder of adapter and not ViewHolder. You have to set onClickListener only once to one element. It's too broad to explain how RecyclerView actually works. I can only say you need more lessons on RecyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set click listeners on recycler items by overriding onBindViewHolder method of adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.myTextView.setOnClickListener(...);
}
```

here you can find an example: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After trying many things, the only one that worked was to add an atribute on the XML of the item layout:
onClick = the name of the method / function you want to trigger